# Storing data in Greasemonkey scripts

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Does GreaseMonkey have something built in so you can store data per-site or per-page?  For example, say you wanted to tweak StackOverflow.com so you can add a note to each of the questions in your favorites list and sort on that note.  Does GreaseMonkey have something built-in to store those notes?  Or perhaps can the scripts self-modify, such that you just define an array or object and keep the data there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes - [GM_setValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue).

> This method allows user script authors to persist simple values across page-loads.
>   Strings, booleans, and integers are currently the only allowed data types

Comment: There's also a library called super_gm_setvalue that allows all types of JavaScript objects to be stored across domains. http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/107941

Answer (score 4):

The values are restricted to the simple datatypes: string, boolean and integer. The values will be stored in Firefox preferences (located in about:config) which is not designed for storing huge amounts of data.

http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue

If GM_setValue doesn't cut it the linked question/answers shows other great possibilities: [alternatives to GM_setValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562972/storing-data-when-using-greasemonkey)

Comment: _Since __Greasemonkey 1.13__ values are saved per userscript in a __SQLite database___

Answer (score 1):

It is really waranted to add that since this question was asked, new APIs were developed for persistent data storage.

### Local storage

Holds string values only, non string values will be converted to string. You can use JSON or your own format to store objects.

Example:

```
localStorage.my_script_value = JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4]);

var my_parsed_value = JSON.parse(localStorage.my_script_value);
```

### [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

More complex, but can hold more data - including binary blobs. Check the MDN article for details.

Example: [Check this on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB).