# Storing data when using Greasemonkey

Tags: database, greasemonkey

Is there a good way to store an extensive amount of data when using Greasemonkey for when `GM_setValue` just doesn't cut it?

Answer (score 5):

Well here are the options:

1. Setup a server to save the data
   for the user, and use xhr to
   create/edit/remove data ([Google App
   Engine (GAE)](http://code.google.com/appengine/) offers a lot of
   free storage space).
2. Use [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) which is
   [implemented in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage).
3. Use [Flash Local Storage](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help02.html).
4. Wait until [Web SQL Database](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/)
   is implemented in Firefox..
5. A mixture of all of the above.

If you write a [Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension) (or in the future you could make a [Jetpack](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/) and use the [Page Mod JEP 107](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Jetpack/Reboot/JEP/107) which is being developed) then you can also read/write/delete files to the [HD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive).

Comment: There's also a library for Greasemonkey that allows the persistent storage of Javascript objects across multiple domains: see here. http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/107941

Answer (score 1):

use Lubemonkey found on Gamecore.org,
works the same as greasemonkey (even the same commands) but you can store the data in an sqlite database using pure SQL (insert,update, selects , joins etc).